# Hiding multiple dynamically-named subdirectories with mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having difficulty configuring a mod_rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to hide certain subdirectories.

Input:
    https://example.com/hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/additional_sub/file.php?lang=en-US

Desired output:
    https://example.com/en-US/additional_sub/file

I had code that allowed me to hide something if I specifically name it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/ hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However, it stopped working once I added in the following language subdirectory code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Besides, the name of the subdirectory is dynamic. "hidden_sub1" might be "random_name243". However, they would always be the first two subdirectories.

So how do I take out the first two randomly-named subdirectories while still keeping the language subdirectory?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If subdirectory names are not fixed as you wrote then where should `/en-US/additional_sub/file` be rewritten to?

Comment: @anubhava For example, if I had https://example.com/en-US/shop/animals/dogs/lab, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/dogs/lab          For https://example.com/en-US/shop/animals/dogs/retriever, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/dogs/retriever         For https://example.com/en-US/shop/animals/snakes/boa, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/snakes/boa     For     https://example.com/en-US/shop/animals/snakes/python, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/snakes/python

Comment: But the shop/animals might be https://example.com/en-US/shop/office/writing/pen, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/writing/pen  or https://example.com/en-US/shop/office/writing/pencil, I'd want https://example.com/en-US/writing/pencil

Comment: Your comments make it clear what you want. Hiding a **static or known** folder is always possible so `shop` can definitely be removed from URLs. However 2nd level folder name is changing where you have `animals` or `office` or may be `products`, `catalog` etc that cannot be removed from client facing URLs. Reason is that some rule must add those hidden folders back internally as well for your code/framework to work. If a URL comes to you as `domain.com/en-US/abc/123` where it should be forwarded internally? `/en-US/shop/animals/abc/123/` OR `/en-US/shop/office/abc/123/`?

Comment: @anubhava I see what you're saying. My brain obviously went on vacation. :/ Thank you for the simple explanation, though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your url from the form

- https://example.com/hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/additional_sub/file.php?lang=en-US

To the form :

- https://example.com/en-US/additional_sub/file

You can use the following Rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#1)externally redirect "/hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/foo.php?lang=bar" to "/bar/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/([^.]+)\.php\?lang=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [L,R=301]
#2)internally rewrite "/bar/foo" to "/hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/foo.php?lang=bar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /hidden_sub1/hidden_sub2/$2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Tested on apache 2.2. and 2.4.**

Comment: But for this, I'd have to write a rule for every hidden_sub1 folder, right? I was hoping for a generic rule that would just hide the first two folders regardless of what they were named. Please see my comments under my question for examples.

Comment: Kindly disregard the last comment. Anubhava has shown me the error in my ways.